# Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core' while Docker Build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-cloud

I am facing this issue while building a Docker via Docker Cloud Building in

```
Docker Cloud's infrastructure...
Cloning into '.'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.1' to the list of known hosts.
Switched to a new branch 'development'
Pulling cache layers for index.docker.io/bheng/iproject-web:latest...
Done!
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-93-generic
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2017-08-17T22:50:04.828747906+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.30
Version: 17.06.1-ce
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: 874a737
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.8.3
Starting build of index.docker.io/bheng/iproject-web:latest...
Step 1/16 : FROM node:9.3.0-alpine as builder
---> cee518159787
Step 2/16 : COPY package.json ./
---> 3d8915b22a32
Removing intermediate container a4c13040dd58
Step 3/16 : RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force
---> Running in 69b80d469997
npm WARN
using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
---> e450d98a30ee
Removing intermediate container 69b80d469997
Step 4/16 : RUN npm i
---> Running in 7c624872d8e3
> node-sass@4.7.2 install /node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js
Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/linux_musl-x64-59_binding.node
Download complete
Binary saved to /node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux_musl-x64-59/binding.node
Caching binary to /root/.npm/node-sass/4.7.2/linux_musl-x64-59_binding.node
> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js
> node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall /node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js
Binary found at /node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux_musl-x64-59/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN @angular/animations@5.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-image-upload@1.0.0-rc.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.4.9 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-image-upload@1.0.0-rc.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.9 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-image-upload@1.0.0-rc.0 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.4.9 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.51 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@0.0.28 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.16 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@0.0.28 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
added 1202 packages in 203.011s
---> fd1a6cff70f6
Removing intermediate container 7c624872d8e3
Step 5/16 : RUN mkdir /web
---> Running in eac64ccf5c19
---> 206fdaf4ed7b
Removing intermediate container eac64ccf5c19
Step 6/16 : RUN cp -R ./node_modules ./web
---> Running in e36f620dd3fb
---> 7d9367fa1f9b
Removing intermediate container e36f620dd3fb
Step 7/16 : WORKDIR /web
---> 0f1b5d4d425b
Removing intermediate container 411e75479d64
Step 8/16 : COPY . .
---> e4e2743df0e0
Removing intermediate container 145a37f072ae
Step 9/16 : RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer
---> Running in 491f4a13f415
module.js:557
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/web/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/tree/virtual.js:10:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
Removing intermediate container 491f4a13f415
The command '/bin/sh -c $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Build failed: The command '/bin/sh -c $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Build failed with exit code 2
ERROR: Build in 'development:/web.dockerfile' (52143fff) failed in 0:07:00
```

**Dockerfile**

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:9.3.0-alpine as builder

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && npm cache clean --force

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm i
RUN mkdir /web
RUN cp -R ./node_modules ./web

WORKDIR /web

COPY . .

## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --build-optimizer

### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.8-alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=builder /web/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/

RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx && \
  chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html

USER nginx
```

How would one debug this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ihue i think its issue angular-cli. what version your angular-cli ?

try to below:

1.editing your package.json changing the line
`"@angular/cli": "1.x.0",`
to
`"@angular/cli": "^1.x.0",`

note: `1.x.0` is your angular-cli version

2.add command to update `npm update -g @angular/cli`

reference of issue [Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9307)